# How to get the chosen source of a picture element before it is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, picture-element

Assuming I have an image in my HTML code and I would like to show a spinner for as long as the image is loading. I could do so by loading the image in JavaScript and once loaded hide the spinner, for example:

```
async loadImage(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image()
    img.onload = () => resolve(img)
    img.onerror = reject
    img.src = src
  }).catch()
}

let image = document.getElementById('#image1')

loadImage(image.src).then(() => {
  // Image loaded, spinner can be hidden.
})
```

Now I am trying to do the same with the HTML `picture` element. Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="image2.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <source srcset="image2.jpg" type="image/jpg" />
  <img src="image2.jpg" />
</picture>
```

Using above JavaScript code it would load the source of the `img` tag which is the JPG version. However the browser might not even choose to load the JPG version but the WebP version. I know of the `currentSrc` property of images but this property only gets applied to the image once the image is loaded.

Basically I need to know which image the browser is loading before it is completely loaded. Does anyone have an idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: checkk for `(load)`

Comment: What do you mean?